# Form not redirecting to the action in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .cshtml file that shows a page of my application. In the application, there is a top menu where there are different buttons. The Code is:-

```
<div id="top_menu">
    <form action="@Url.Action("Pause", new { sessionId = Model, schoolId = ViewData["SchoolId"] })" method="post">
        <button type="submit">Pause</button>
    </form>

    <button id="score_button" type="button" class="text-group">
        <span>Score:</span>
        <span style="font-size: 1.5em" data-bind="text: score"></span>
    </button>

    <span id="elapsed_time" class="text-group">
        <span>Time elapsed:</span>
        <span style="font-size: 1.5em" data-bind="text: time"></span>
    </span>

    <button type="button" onclick="SR.ERSIM.showInfo('info_resources')">
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Resources
    </button>

    <form action="@Url.Action("Instructions")" method="get" target="_blank">
        <button type="submit">
            <i class="far fa-life-ring"></i> Help
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now every other thing works fine but the last button "Help" should redirect to the Instructions action of the Controller but it always redirects to the Index Action of the Controller. I cannot figure out this issue. How can I Redirect to the Instructions action?

My Controller Code for it:-

```cs
[Route("Schools/{schoolId:int}/VC/EmergencyRoom")]
public EmergencyRoomController(IEmergencyRoomRepository emergencyRoomRepository,
    EmergencyRoomService emergencyRoomService, ISessionRepository sessionRepository)
{
    this.emergencyRoomRepository = emergencyRoomRepository;
    this.emergencyRoomService = emergencyRoomService;
    this.sessionRepository = sessionRepository;
}

[HttpGet("{sessionId:long}")]
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(long sessionId, int schoolId)
{
    Sessions session = await this.sessionRepository.GetSessionAsync(sessionId, 
        this.User.GetUserId());
    if (session == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
   
    ViewData["SchoolId"] = schoolId;
    return this.View(session.Id);
}

[HttpGet("Instructions")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ViewResult Instructions()
{
    return this.View();
}
```

Comment: Is the form nested within another form?  If so, that's not legal HTML.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on Instruction method and see it's reaching on that method or Instuctions method. I gett target _bank might be the culprit remove that target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Help form like this:

```
<form action="Instructions" method="get" target="_blank">
    <button type="submit">
        <i class="far fa-life-ring"></i> Help
    </button>
</form>
```